# Adding my own dylibs to homebrew

Tags: osx-lion, homebrew, afp

I'm trying to install [liberate](https://github.com/joshado/liberate-applefileserver), which I want to put in `/usr/local/lib`. However, when I do this, homebrew complains about a `Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib`.

What's the best way to add my own dylibs to /usr/local/lib? I don't mind creating my own formula if I have to, but it seems a bit too complicated for what I want to do. (And I've never done it before, so I'd like to avoid it if possible.)